# How to override Magento 2 core files example?

Tags: magento-2.1

How to override Magento 2 core files explain here.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below link:
https://belvg.com/blog/override-a-layout-in-magento-2.html
You will get the flow of Magento2 overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Create New Module to override Magento 2 Core files. For module you have to create below files.

**app/code/Namespace/Module/registration.php**

**app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/module.xml**

**Controller Override**

**app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index" type="Namespace\Module\Controller\Cart\Index" /> 
</config>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/Controller/Cart/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Cart;
class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index
{
    public function execute()
    { 
    }
}
```